# using function to loop in R

Tags: r

I have this char vector,

```
 sentence <- c("Learning", "loops", "in", "R", "is", "not", "that", "bad")
```

and I'm trying to make a loop that loops over the possible word lengths, and then returns a message that details the length of each word. for example, If I input the vector position 1, it should return that "Learning" has 8 letters in it.

So it will display the one that matches the length I enter.

any Ideas on where I can start, I know I can use `nchar()` function to help but I am new and doesn't know exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of akrun's answer

```
sentence <- c("Learning", "loops", "in", "R", "is", "not", "that", "bad")
ncharacter <- sapply(sentence,nchar)
responses <- paste0((dQuote(names(ncharacter))), " has ", ncharacter ," letters in it.")
> responses
[1] "“Learning” has 8 letters in it." "“loops” has 5 letters in it."    "“in” has 2 letters in it."      
[4] "“R” has 1 letters in it."        "“is” has 2 letters in it."       "“not” has 3 letters in it."     
[7] "“that” has 4 letters in it."     "“bad” has 3 letters in it."
```

Some enhancements

1. Change double quotes to single quote for readability
2. add singular/plural detections

```
responses2 <- case_when(ncharacter==1~paste0((sQuote(names(ncharacter))), " has ", ncharacter ," letter in it."),
          ncharacter>1~paste0((sQuote(names(ncharacter))), " has ", ncharacter ," letters in it."),
          T~NA_character_)

> responses2
[1] "‘Learning’ has 8 letters in it." "‘loops’ has 5 letters in it."    "‘in’ has 2 letters in it."      
[4] "‘R’ has 1 letter in it."         "‘is’ has 2 letters in it."       "‘not’ has 3 letters in it."     
[7] "‘that’ has 4 letters in it."     "‘bad’ has 3 letters in it."
```

Turn this into functions:

```
#Original
check_ncharacters <- function(sentence){
  ncharacter <- sapply(sentence,nchar)
  responses <- paste0((dQuote(names(ncharacter))), " has ", ncharacter ," letters in it.")
  responses
}
> check_ncharacters(sentence)
[1] "“Learning” has 8 letters in it." "“loops” has 5 letters in it."    "“in” has 2 letters in it."      
[4] "“R” has 1 letters in it."        "“is” has 2 letters in it."       "“not” has 3 letters in it."     
[7] "“that” has 4 letters in it."     "“bad” has 3 letters in it."  

  
#With enhancement
check_ncharacters2 <- function(sentence){
  ncharacter <- sapply(sentence,nchar)
  responses2 <- case_when(ncharacter==1~paste0((sQuote(names(ncharacter))), " has ", ncharacter ," letter in it."),
                          ncharacter>1~paste0((sQuote(names(ncharacter))), " has ", ncharacter ," letters in it."),
                          T~NA_character_)
  responses2
}
check_ncharacters2(sentence)
> check_ncharacters2(sentence)
[1] "‘Learning’ has 8 letters in it." "‘loops’ has 5 letters in it."    "‘in’ has 2 letters in it."      
[4] "‘R’ has 1 letter in it."         "‘is’ has 2 letters in it."       "‘not’ has 3 letters in it."     
[7] "‘that’ has 4 letters in it."     "‘bad’ has 3 letters in it."
```

Comment: so to check the word Learning I have to write check_ncharacter( == 1) ?

Comment: if you just want the word learning use check_ncharacters(sentence[1])

Comment: or check_ncharacters("Learning")